# Creating two databases and match

Tags: php

I'm a begginer in php. Currently i'm doing a project involved two database connection. In which, one is `student.db` and one is `library.db`. After the user login (student.db), they must be displayed with the books (library.db) that matches with the subject that they are taking current semester. I'm confused on how to do the matching process.

I tried linking using

```sql
SELECT library.codes, library.book_name, library.link
FROM library_db.library library
LEFT JOIN registrar_db.student student
    ON library.codes = student.subject1
WHERE student.subject1 IS NOT NULL
```

it does not display anything. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: One thing I will mention that `LEFT JOIN ON X WHERE X IS NOT NULL` is kind of redundant. Just use `JOIN` alone (no `LEFT`, no `IS NOT NULL`) because that's built-in like that.

Comment: basically this project is a library system. in which it has two databases ,one library.db and another is student.db. so, the system is about when the student login using their id and password, the will straight get the list of books and book link(which is in library.db) according to the subjects that they have enrolled current semester. i have done with admin part which add edit and delete. now im stucked with the matching process of two database which i know it is supposed to use if else statement. but i dont know where  and how to use

Comment: Well, have you checked for errors? Depending on which MySQL library you're using, it would be `mysql_error()` or an equivalent function. In PDO you can set the mode to throw exceptions, otherwise errors would be silent.

Comment: it didnt show any error. when i refresh the page it looks the same .

Comment: is that in the display page, i need to add the connection of two database?